# Is the LongAdder a wrong choice for the ID generator?

Tags: java, java-8

Java's `LongAdder` is more performant then `AtomicLong`. However, if I am getting this correctly, it is not a good choice for the ID generator, because there is no atomic 'read-and-increment' operation.

I am asking this because I see people recommend it for the ID generation, and I do not see the point since the `sum()` will be called for every operation.

Is the `LongAdder` a good or bad choice for the simple long ID generator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have already answered your own question. It is definitely overkill for id generation from single thread and is not usable in multi-threaded scenario because there is no atomic `incrementAndGet` like operation. So the answer has to be it is not a good choice.

As javadoc says this class is useful for things like collecting statistics and such where contention is potentially high:

> This class is usually preferable to `AtomicLong` when
>     multiple threads update a common sum that is used for purposes such
>     as collecting statistics, not for fine-grained synchronization
>     control.

Comment: …or when you know that there will be a point in the future where you can read the final result without contention. Surely not the case for an ID generator.

Answer (score 6):

First is that *Java's LongAdder is more performant then AtomicLong* is not *very correct* either. It is the case if there is high contention over it - otherwise it's just the same as `AtomicLong` internally. But even so - you should be aware that it uses some extra space so that each Thread computes the result separately, so when `sum` is called it just gathers those results.

But definitely not a good choice for an `ID` generator, either way.